# ldapmodify error - Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: no global superior knowledge

Tags: linux, openldap

Ok guys, I've been beating my head against the wall over this one all day, and I'm getting nowhere. I'm trying to run ldapmodify against OpenLDAP in a script to update a couple of attributes for a series of hosts. No matter what I do, I get "Server is unwilling to perform... no global superior knowledge."

Here's my code, with dummy values inserted. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
for sys in <system names>; do
  ldapmodify -x -c -h localhost -D uid=name,dc=example,dc=com -w ${password} <<EOF
    dn: hostname=${sys},ou=computers,location=code,dc=example,dc=com
    changetype: modify
    replace: ip
    ip: new.host.ip.address
    -
    replace: printer
    printer: new.printer.ip.address
EOF
done
```

The DN matches the DN provided by ldapsearch perfectly, so I don't see how it could be the problem. Like I said though, I just don't see the problem, so any suggestions are welcome.

Also, the suffix in slapd.conf is dc=example,dc=com.

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing how the little things can bite you so hard.  Since this was in a script, I indented the command section to keep with coding conventions.  Apparently, ldapmodify interpreted the white space as part of the commands/data and got confused.  I reformatted it to look like this, and now it works:

```
for sys in <system names>; do
  ldapmodify -x -c -h localhost -D uid=name,dc=example,dc=com -w ${password} <<EOF
dn: hostname=${sys},ou=computers,location=code,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: ip
ip: new.host.ip.address
-
replace: printer
printer: new.printer.ip.address
EOF
done
```

Comment: That's more an issue with using a shell + `here document` than it is with ldapmodify.